# WAMP or Codeigniter serious upload bug - cannot upload files

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I am getting mad trying to achieve something that is supposed to be very simple. First of all, I have the following upload form that **works flawlessly under OS X + XAMPP**. When moving this script to **WAMP + Windows Server**, I get serious problems during the file upload. I am using Codeigniter.

```
public function importExcel () {        
    $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!($this->upload->do_upload())) {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
    $data['filename'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
}
```

This is my simple function. The upload folder is located under **www/mywebsite/**. Codeigniter's config.php file is configured correctly.

When I try to upload a xls file, the server **crashes** (interrupting its connection). Meaning that I get [**this page**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIopt.png) with error: **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**, instead of showing me the upload errors.

Here is what I can say:

- The file is not uploaded and I cannot find it in the upload folder.
- The file upload actually starts, I see in the bar below the browser window that it is loading the file. When it comes to 100% percentage, I get the page linked above.

Here is what I have tried:

- **Changing the upload folder to /upload/, ./upload/ and stuff**. When I tried to do ../upload/, i get the error and the page doesn't crash. It says he cannot find the right folder. This means that the folder is found during the upload and the problem is somewhere else.
- **Adding the xls MIME type to .htaccess**.

Here is my actual .htaccess file in case it could be necessary.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteBase /websitefolder/
```

I repeat that this same code works good under OS X + XAMPP with the same directory structure.

---

EDIT: forgot to say I tried to upload xls of any kind and any size, even very little. This has nothing to do with upload limit probably, I already raised up the variables.

---

EDIT 2: my PHP error log is totally empty. These are the rows that get added to my Apace error log when I try the upload.

```
[Tue May 27 14:22:54 2014] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0d PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Server built: Sep 24 2011 19:57:51
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4736
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Child 4736: Child process is running
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Child 4736: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Child 4736: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Child 4736: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue May 27 14:22:56 2014] [notice] Child 4736: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

---

EDIT 3: tested a non-with-Codeigniter file upload by using **[w3schools sample code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)**. I get:

```
Upload: test.php
Type: application/octet-stream
Size: 26.90234375 kB
Stored in: C:\Wamp\tmp\phpAAB5.tmp
```

But when I go in C:\Wamp\tmp I cannot see the file. There are other temporary files of the same kind however. By using the code under **Saving the Uploaded File** the upload works correctly and I CAN find the file I uploaded.

---

I am desperate  because I need this for a client. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: I know this is pretty basic, but have you checked for permissions in the file upload folder? Have you checked the Apache and PHP logs from WAMPP? There could be some usefull info there.

Comment: Agree with Christian -> having had this problem a long time ago with blueimp uploader on windows box I found I had to set permissions to 777 -> which is scary -> but then once uploaded a file could change the permissions to something more acceptable and everything worked from then onwards.

Comment: Also check that the temp directory is writeable -> I seem to remember that was also an issue.

Comment: I checked the logs already, I will update the main post now. PHP error log is empty. The Apache one is actually full of things. I cannot go 777 under Windows, but System, Administrator and Users have Full Access set.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie do you mean the temp directory made by Codeigniter? As far as I know no temp is created..

Comment: I would be tempted to go back to first principles as this point and forget frameworks and xml files and ensure that simple file upload using a one page script actually allows you to upload files. It will make debugging a lot easier. Is there another example of file upload that works using the windows server?

Comment: I did it and something is wrong imho. Updating main post right now, refresh in a few secs.

Comment: There is no section: 'Saving the Uploaded File', however, are you now saying that you can correctly upload the files you want to the server?

Comment: if it is all ok now. Then feel free to add your own answer of what was wrong as that may help others. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has probably something to do with CodeIgniter libraries. Using the same code provided by the official documentation I am still NOT able to upload xls documents but I was able to achieve this by using the corresponding, standard PHP upload form.

Codeigniter is not able to upload the file and while performing this check:

```
if (!($this->upload->do_upload())) {
   echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

The web application crashes instead of returning the error. If I disable this check, I get no errors but clearly the file is not uploaded.

I will report this Stackoverflow discussion to the Codeigniter community and see if they can confirm what I just wrote.

Comment: 1) phew - happy client ;-) and 2) thanks for posting the update.

Comment: Minimum I could do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'upload/';
```

path need to be set to abolute path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /websitefolder/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is how should look your .htaccess

and dont forget to remove index.php in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: Is your website under subfolder in www ??? in this case you need to chager htacces to this RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /website/

Comment: yes it is in a subfolder, but it is working correctly under XAMPP. Why should this change?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't do it

Answer (score 1):

Write

> RewriteBase /

if its hosted on root other wise add directory name like

> RewriteBase /testfolder/

Comment: Please try to change your upload path variable with this $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';